# ISE as RADIUS server or not in EAP-TLS authentication

Tags: authentication, radius, tacacs, cisco-ise, authorization

Does the ISE server act as a RADIUS server to a Switch proxying a supplicant certificate, or does it use some other protocol? This is for EAP-TLS based auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the ISE server act as a RADIUS server to a Switch proxying a supplicant certificate, or does it use some other protocol? This is for EAP-TLS based auth

Whenever you have an EAP based authentication, a RADIUS server of some sort is involved. This could be ISE (Cisco's current RADIUS server product) or some other RADIUS server solution.

Like many vendor based RADIUS solutions, ISE has additional functionality; in this case specifically functionality that is meant to extend and enhance the interaction with other Cisco products and platforms.